# I'm currently trying to make a CNN (Convolutional Neural Network) Model, and the cv2.imread is not functioning properly

Tags: python, opencv, conv-neural-network

```
img_paths_train = glob('pneumonia/train/*/*.jpeg')
path = img_paths_train
img = cv2.imread(path)
print(img.shape)
plt.imshow(img)

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-40b7b3a73036> in <module>()
      4 img_paths_train = glob('pneumonia/train/*/*.jpeg')
      5 path = img_paths_train
----> 6 img = cv2.imread(path)
      7 print(img.shape)
      8 plt.imshow(img)

SystemError: <built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error
```

I don't know whats wrong with the cv2. imread, I tried putting to to cv2.imread(0) too, but that doesn't work for me as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

cv2.imread() method loads an image from the specified file.
It will show single image at a time.  You may need to loop over the files in a directory to show all images one by one.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be easily rectified by iterating through each image file and calling cv2.imread() on it.

Let me explain what I mean by this. You have used glob to return the file path of all the images. Now cv2.imread() accepts only one file and not a list of files. But you are passing a list of files. Hence the error. Try doing this instead:-

```
img_paths_train = glob('pneumonia/train/*/*.jpeg')
path = img_paths_train
for image in path:
    img = cv2.imread(image)
    print(img.shape)
    plt.imshow(img)
```